# How do I overwrite an element from an array?

Tags: java

Can anyone of you help me overwrite something from my Spherocylinder array?

I've got this currently:

```
   public Spherocylinder deleteSpherocylinder(String labelIn)
   {
      Spherocylinder result = null;
      int index = 0;      

      for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
      {
         if (object[i].getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase(labelIn))
         {
            //My issue is with the line of code below, i know this is 
            //how i delete an element in an arraylist but i know want to 
            //delete it using an array.
            result = object.remove(i);
         }
      }

      return result;
   }
```

where (object) is the name of my Spherocylinder array and (elements) is an int I use which tells me how many elements i have in my array. This line of code is just one of my methods in my class, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't, use an `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: You can't. By definition, an array has fixed length. If you want to delete an element, use an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "remove" and element from an array. Arrays have a fixed length, so you can only overwrite the value in a cell.

What you might be looking for, is maybe overwriting the value you want to "remove" with say the last value or shifting all values by one (which is what `ArrayList.remove()` does.

Comment: Oh right I remember that now, could you please tell me exactly how i would overwrite the value based on my code. I've been working on this one method for hours but can't seem to get it, thanks.